# About access control in hyperledger composer to implement a business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I try to use composer to develop a block-chain web app.
I write the ".acl" file to implement access control, and I also issued different IDs to different participant, then I start the REST server.

The next thing I want to ask is, how can the REST server identify my identity?

Just like, one kind of participant is named "trader", I specify "trader" cannot access function "A" in chaincode, but REST server generate the API of "A", then I write a simple html file and send a POST request to localhost:3000, I can invoke this function directly. I even don't know I access this interface by what kind of identity.

I am confused about this, can some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember how you started the REST server? You had to specify a **business network card**, and likely it was the card for the admin with all reading and writing rights. Also most likely, you disabled **authentication with passport**.

With these two elements, of course you can always do anything just by calling any available API function.

You can refer to the [passport authentication instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/getting-started-rest-api) for `composer-rest-server` to implement your authentication scheme.

You should code the rules for what is allowed for certain groups (such as "patients", "doctors", "payers") in the ACL permission files. Refer to the section "Granting Network Access Control" in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language, which contains some pretty similar examples.

Illicit API calls would then simply fail if attempted by the wrong entity.

Comment: Thanks, as you say, if I want to apply access control, I must use different cards with different authority to deploy different REST server?

Comment: I am trying to develop an app of medical insurance, there are three identities of participant: patient, doctor and insurer. But I think it is impossible to generate identity card fro every specific participant, I just want to generate REST API for all doctors, patients and insurers partially, how can I implement this?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know how to write the .acl file, but what I mean is how can I access REST server by different identities? Now I can just change the IDs and test the .acl on playground instead of the REST server. If I start the REST server with admin@tutorial-network, the identity of me will always be "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin" , right?

Comment: You have to implement an authentication scheme and start the rest server with the `-a true` flag. Both described [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication).

Comment: Thanks! Now I am familiar with the complete process